# Django and mod_python intermittent error?

Tags: django, mod-python

I have a Django site at http://sm.rutgers.edu/relive/af_api/index/. It is supposed to display "**Home of the relive APIs**". If you refresh this page many times, you can see different renderings.

1) The expected page.

2) Django "It worked!" page.

3) "ImportError at /index/" page. If you scroll down enough to `ROOT_URLCONF` part, you will see it says `'relive.urls'`. But apparently, it should be `'af_api.urls'`, which is in my `settings.py` file.

Since these results happen randomly, is it possible that either Django or mod_python is working unstably?

Comment: Looks like you've got different apache children serving different versions/ages of your code. Have you restarted Apache properly?

Comment: @stevejalim I used to have a Django project at its parent folder `relive`. Then I deleted that and started a new project in the folder `af_api`, which is a subfolder of `relive`. I did not restart Apache because I was told by my system administrator that mod_python does not require restarting Apache to take effect new changes.

Comment: your sysadmin's wrong. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/#running-a-development-server-with-mod-python -> the implication (and reality) is you need to restart Apache (or do a reload for a more graceful experience) every time you deploy code changes to that server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to stevejalim, I asked my sysadmin to restart Apache. Now the issue is gone!